# Custom Font STILL wont work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face, custom-font

The webpage where I'm trying to get the custom font "Duke-Fill" to display is http://www.hamlinforcongress.com/helpout.php

I'm using:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'header_font';
src: url('Duke-Fill.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('Duke-Fill.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('Duke-Fill.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('Duke-Fill.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
.header_font{
font-family: header_font;
}
```

I've tried every other suggestion I can find on the Internet, but nothing can make the custom font display in Internet Explorer.  It works perfectly in every other conceivable browser, but not IE (surprise surprise).  Help?

Comment: Can you check with developer toolbar what error is it giving you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NimbusSanConD-Lig';
    src: url('fonts/228BFB_1_0.eot');
    src: url('fonts/228BFB_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/228BFB_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/228BFB_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This code works in IE. It was generated using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: No but they can quite easily adjust that part of it so didn't seem worth changing it. The main part of the answer is use Font Squirrel.

Comment: He need's that font to work on his web page, else he can go for Google web fonts..

Comment: Yes but he can easily change the font part of the code or use Font Squirrel as I pointed out. The name of the font and file aren't relevant. The code is.

Comment: @SpaceBeers - I was reffering to the font file - not every font file works the same - I had problems with using fontquirell since even with their complete code the font won't show up IE. The fix waw running the font trough a converter that changes some font internal settings - just can't remember which one was it.

Comment: @easwee - Fair point. There's one way to find out with this one then. It works with most fonts from my experience so hopefully it will for this one.

Comment: hey wait I caught something here, did you see there's no eot file? like the 1 in yours

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Yep literally just saw that. I'm fairly sure just throwing the font file he's got through  Font Squirrel will solve the problem (I don't work for them or anything btw, it's just a useful tool).

Comment: @SpaceBeers I know it bro, don't worry, I am aware that it's a nice tool, but I prefer to stick with Google Web Fonts(I don't work for them lol) ;)

Comment: Jup I would direct him to do this too first. Than if that fails I got one more trick up in the sleve.

Comment: @easwee - My last trick is normally give up and use Google Fonts :)

Comment: @SpaceBeers Google Web Fonts always recommended!

Comment: @SpaceBeers - I don't stop at that - want it to work as intended :)

Comment: Cool. @easwee - what's your other trick just out of interest?

Comment: @SpaceBeers - I once had a weird caligraphy font to embed and it just wouldn't work - than I found out that each TTF font file can come locked (there's an "embedable" property that the font designer can set to prevent sistem from embeding the font). However there's also a tool called TTFPATCH that will enable you to change this setting and make the font usable. This happened to me with 2 fonts till now and I solved it with this (altough I think that this might be problematic from a legal point of view - but the client was not concerned with and since they took all risks I just implemented it)

Comment: @easwee - Interesting, but yeah, legally v. dodgy.