# Internet Explorer doesn't recognize font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to have custom made social media icons on my webpage. I am using socicon font. My code works for all browsers except for IE11. I even tried the ?#ie fix and it still didn't work. I have also read that I need to put the Full Name in order for IE11 to recognize the font. I believe that socicon is the full name, but when I type that in it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'si';
    src: url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181041/file-1984135345-eot/Font/socicon.eot');
    src: url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181041/file-1984135345-eot/Font/socicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181041/file-1984135350-woff/Font/socicon.woff') format('woff'),
          url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181041/file-1981225289-ttf/Font/socicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('h ttp://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181041/file-1979860473-svg/Font/socicon.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

It is also odd that when I tried to erase this line:

```
src: url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181041/file-1984135345-eot/Font/socicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
```

Safari also no longer produced the socicon font. I didn't think Safari read .eot files.

Thanks,

Megan

Comment: Try checking the solution in this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722959/custom-font-still-wont-work-in-ie

Comment: Some fonts cant be converted to EOT fonts. I had that problem too. Ask the author to make an EOT font for you, or ask if he has one.

Comment: I generated the social media icons from perfecticons.com and they provided me with .eot, .woff, .ttf, and .svg font files, along with html and css code. All I was supposed to do was copy/paste the code into the correct areas on my website. The icons work perfectly on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. IE11 is the only browser giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If your IE is above 8, then I would suggest you to convert the fonts to .woff format. I've had that problem before and this was the solution to it.

Feed your eot fonts in something like [**this**](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) and simply convert them to .woff. Then, give it another try.

edit: Try to use local fonts

Comment: I can't use a local font because I need the social media logos to show. I thought IE used the .eot format not .woff.

Comment: @Megan It does. IE supports .eot format and since version 9 it also supports .woff format. I recommend woff, in case you have IE9 or higher, because .woff format has a much wider spectrum of browser compatibility. See for your self here-> [.woff](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff) and here-> [.eot](http://caniuse.com/#search=eot). Also, from my experience, being a compressed format, .woff tens to be a more lightweight font.